# C# DataGridView proper way to get column values for selected row, FullRowSelect

Tags: c#, datagridview, fullrowselect

I'm using a DataGridView to display data, in the FullRowSelect mode.

My code follows:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            currentColumn1Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            currentColumn2Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //do something with the values
        }

    }
```

The view has only 2 columns and if the cell in the left column is selected, it returns the values.  But, if I select the row by clicking in the right column, the values read empty.

What is the best way extract the selected cell values using this row selection method?

Comment: Don't use the `CellContentClick` unless you mean it. It fires only if, yup, you can guess it now, you actually hit the cell's __content__. Use the `CellClick` instead!

Comment: Wow... how did I miss that?  Thank you!!!